# Update Sharepoint Using NTLM

Tags: node.js, http, npm, ntlm

I need help to use NTML (node.js) package . I want to update data in sharepoint server using NTML node.js libaray.  I need to know about ntml

1. how to use it ntlm?
2. how to get data from sharepoint server
3. what are necessary parameters to post data for updation

Please how to do it with an easy way? Please any example..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I am going to give answer on my own asked question I found solutions by using HTTPNTLM package.

By using

```
npm install httpntlm
```

here is link how to use it  [USE OF NTML](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/SamDecrock/node-http-ntlm)